# Symfony 5.4 problem with using Unique and Hostname together

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I am trying to use Unique and Hostname constraint together in Syfony 5.4 entity. Lets have:

```
    /**
 * @ORM\Column(name="domain", type="string", length=150, nullable=false, unique=true)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Hostname()
 */
private $domain;
```

This validate without problems. But when I add Unique constraint, it fails with message - This value should be of type array|IteratorAggregate.

```
    /**
 * @ORM\Column(name="domain", type="string", length=150, nullable=false, unique=true)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Unique()
 * @Assert\Hostname()
 */
private $domain;
```

I need both validation, yes, in this case it fails on database INSERT, but I want to validate form. How is correct way?

Thank you
DR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to validate that the domain (or hostname) is unique inside the database table. In that case, you would have to use `UniqueEntity` see https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html.

It is worth mentioning that this doesn't protect you against race conditions.

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @UniqueEntity("domain")
 */
class YourEntity
{
   /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="domain", type="string", length=150, nullable=false, unique=true)
    * @Assert\NotBlank()
    * @Assert\Hostname()
    */
    protected $domain;
}
```

Comment: Ok, this is working, thank you. But it doesnt show message in form (its logic, because with UniqueEntity is hard to say, which element of form is validated). But why is not working Unique and Hostname together?

Comment: Hm, my fault, I am using Unique for long time, but it looks that bady. In doc I can read "This constraint can be applied to any property of type array or \Traversable." Question is why is working for all time correctly...